# NSNumber as parameters passed in a block in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, block, objective-c-blocks

I'm learning to use blocks in my writing but When I try to create one of them the compiler reports a really strange error! For example for the following code:

```
NSNumber *(^eseguiIlCalcolo)(void)=
^{

};
```

the compiler reports the following error:

```
Incompatible block pointer types initializing 'NSNumber
*(^_strong)(void)' with an expression of type 'void(^)(void)'
```

Where's the error? Can I fix it? Is this related to ARC?

Comment: It sounds like the problem is not with the definition itself, but rather it's where you're trying to use the block. Show the code where you try to use `eseguiIlCalcolo` for more elaboration.

Comment: that is not strange message, because the return type is missing for the block, check my answer for further details.

Comment: @mah No, it's not, just read the error message.

Comment: @holex I see -- I was thinking the question simply omitted the contents of the block from the question for brevity (and that the block was being passed into a method requiring one returning void).

Comment: @H2CO3 yep -- see my response to holex, and thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

returns an `NSNumber` object:

```
NSNumber * (^ReturnNumber)(void) = ^NSNumber *(void) { // the keyword void is not necessary to write here
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:9];
};
```

expects an `NSNumber` object as parameter:

```
void (^ExpectNumber)(NSNumber *) = ^(NSNumber * number) {
    NSLog(@"%@", number);
};
```

Comment: yes that's right, so I have to declare first and then write my block, right?

Comment: @user3005039 No, it's not that you have to declare it first without initialization (if that's what you mean). It's only that you have to initialize it with the **correct** type of block.

Comment: @user3005039 The key issue is that if your block is defined to return a `NSNumber`, then the block actually has to return a `NSNumber`. If you want to fully (and somewhat redundantly) define the block variable as shown above, you can do that (that's a stylistic observation). But the key is that when you assign that block variable, you must use a block that returns the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

You have declared a block variable which points to a block that returns an `NSNumber`. However, you tried to initialize it with a block that doesn't return anything. You have to insert a `return` statement in the body of the block in order the compiler to infer its return type:

```
NSNumber *(^blk)(void) = ^{
    return @(1); // or [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], etc.
};
```

Comment: @holex No, it isn't. The compiler infers the return type from the type of the expression in the `return` statement.

Comment: @holex This has nothing to do with compilers being or not being "new", nor is it a "standard" or "non-standard" way -- unfortunately, Objective-C hasn't got a standard, so there's no "standard" way to define blocks. It either compiles (which it does) and then it's syntactically correct, or it does not, in which case it's wrong. [Here, have some proof](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4960980/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-29%20at%202.24.00%20PM.png).

Comment: that is not my problem; that is the developers' problem who are not able to solve a simple error when they work with blocks; probably it happens because they are lack of knowledge of the industrial standards. anyway, no hard feelings, just an opinion.

Comment: @holex I don't see how this is a problem. Conversely, this **solves** OP's problem, that's why I posted it as an answer.

Comment: ...as my answer does too, but there is no problem here for me. I only mentioned you to use the proper definitions of blocks, if you would not like to do this, that is okay.

Comment: @holex "the return type is still missing". According to [Blocks Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxDeclaringCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH4-SW1) says, "If you don’t explicitly declare the return value of a block expression, it can be automatically inferred from the contents of the block." None of their samples explicitly declare the return type, and I almost never see that in practice. Parameters are always included (if not `void`), but return types rarely.

Comment: @Rob, if someone is smart enough to read the official documentation what you linked (I don't mean you now personally but in general), that person will understand it; but if someone write a post here to ask obvious questions, that person has no definite idea what they are doing; therefore it would be better them to be taught the correct way not only the shortcuts, which they might not memorise for long term.